# Why is a whole row changed in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++

Using visual studio forms.

In file1.h I have a class with a private bool that is set to false.

```cpp
public class Tile
{
private:
    bool hasBomb = false;

public:
    bool getBomb() { return hasBomb; }
    void setBomb(bool set) { hasBomb = set; }
...
```

In file2.h I make a two-dimensional array of it

```cpp
...
namespace {
    Tile tiles[sizeX][sizeY];
}
...
```

I set one to true, and test it

```cpp
...
tiles[0, 0]->setBomb(true);

MessageBox::Show("" + tiles[0, 0]->getBomb()); // returns True
MessageBox::Show("" + tiles[1, 0]->getBomb()); // also returns True ???
MessageBox::Show("" + tiles[0, 1]->getBomb()); // returns False
...
```

But as you can see my whole row gets turned to true, and I don't understand why.

Why is that and how do I fix that?

Comment: Get informed about what the comma operator actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tiles[0, 0]->setBomb(true);
```

This is not the correct way to access a two dimensional array, use double `[]` instead:

```
tiles[0][0]->setBomb(true);
```

Your code snippet is actually using `operator,`.

This operator evaluates its first operand, then discards it and returns the second operand. Which means your current code is equivalent to:

```
tiles[0]->setBomb(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write like this to access a 2D array.

```
tiles[0][0]->setBomb(true);
cout << tiles[0][0]->getBomb()<<endl;
cout << tiles[1][0]->getBomb()<<endl;
cout << tiles[0][1]->getBomb()<<endl;
```

Comment: Please explain why. Mention the `,` operator and what it does.